# Is it OK to use XSPF for video content?

Tags: flv, flvplayback, xspf

Is it OK to use XSPF for video content?

If not, what else should be used?

I am targeting flash players, including Jeroen Wijering's JW FLV media player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, XSPF is suitable for "video playlists".

Let me invite you to the XSPF mailing list:
http://lists.musicbrainz.org/mailman/listinfo/playlist

See you,

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You can stream directly in FLV and I believe this is the most desirable solution.

Check out the FLV capabilities (including streaming) of [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/)

Answer (score -1):

Sure it is ok ...
The http://feedpixel.com  converts a podcast RSS feed to xspf format before play ...